# how to access Multiple form in controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have to do form validation for multiple forms which have to be created dynamically. I have created the forms dynamically by using ng-repeat 
but I am not able to access that form in controller.

Please check the code:

```
 <button ng-click="navigate()">Next</button>
   <div ng-repeat="service in services">
     <ng-form name="mainform">
        <div ng-repeat="spec in service.products">
           <ng-form name="subform">
               <input type="text" name="{{spec.name}}" ng-model="spec.value">
               <span ng-show="subform[spec.name].$invalid">please enter</span>
           </ng-form>
        </div>
    </ng-form> 
  </div >
```

It is working fine, but I need to check whether at least one of mainform's subforms is valid or not after clicked on next button so I have tried to access this in controller like this:

```
 $scope.navigate=function(){
     console.log($scope.mainform.subform);
     console.log($scope.subform);
 }
```

but I am getting `undefined` for both console logs. How can I access multiple dynamically created forms in the controller?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<ng-form [name="mainform"]>` ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with these forms in controller?

Comment: I want to check in controller that at least any one of the mainform has all valid data in subform

Comment: This probably is one of the reasons [HTML disallows nested forms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/379610/215552)....

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to do with forms in controller?

Looks like you don't need it.

You have forms hierarchy. Pseudocode:

```
ng-form mainForm
  ng-form subFormOne
  ng-form subFormTwo
```

If `subFormOne` or `subFormTwo` is invalid then `mainForm` will be invalid too. If all sub forms are valid then `mainForm` will be valid too. You will check only `mainForm.$valid` in your code.

If you need to style it somehow you I recommend you to use css there. ngForm directive adds classes to the element. You can use .ng-form selector in css to add styles to your form. For example:

```
.ng-form.ng-invalid {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Here is [plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZOxLh5LStre0vRCFYmWN?p=preview).

Comment: controller file how to do that ? ....I have tried like this but getting error ...

Comment: $scope.navigate=function(){console.log($scope.mainform.$invalid)}

Comment: I added the plunkr example

Comment: If you have form name "mainForm" you have to use: `console.log($scope.mainForm.$inva‌​lid)`

Comment: in your code mainform is not a ng-repeat one ...it is kind of static ...but if you look at my code there is two form one is mainform another one is subform both will be created using ng-repeat ...you code won't work when there is both forms are dynamically created ...

Comment: Yes `mainForm` is not in ngRepeat, like in your code. Your `mainform` is not in ngRepeat too. When you have hierarchy you don't care how many forms there are in ngRepeat. Thats the main point. If you will see my plunkr example you will get that I have 3 subsforms which are dynamically created by ngRepeat. Exactly like in your code.

Comment: You said you need to access subforms for controller. I asked you why? The answer was: to get if they are invalid. You can check if **all** forms are valid or **not** valid by checking parent form `mainForm`. The solution is in my plunkr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129971/discussion-between-silvesterprabu-and-sharikov-vladislav).

Answer (score 1):

The logs show `undefined` because because the `ng-repeat` directive creates child scopes and the forms are put on those child scopes.

Create a form at the top level, above the `ng-repeat`:

```
<button ng-click="navigate()">Next</button>

<!-- ADD top form above ng-repeat -->
<ng-form name=top>
    <div ng-repeat="service in services">
        <ng-form name="mainform_{{$index}}">
            <div ng-repeat="spec in service.products">
                 <ng-form name="subform_{{$index}}">
                     <input name="{{spec.name}}" ng-model="spec.value">
                 </ng-form>
            </div>
        </ng-form> 
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

Then forms inside the `ng-repeat` will be visible:

```
$scope.navigate=function(){
     console.log($scope.top);
     console.log($scope.top.mainform_0);
     console.log($scope.top.mainform_0.subform_0);
};
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/9TxgzOSEr826xi9l0keE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I would use $index from ng-repeat or something makes it unique.

UPDATE: 12/6/2016 Based on the comment.

[plnkr of deeply nested dynamic forms and validation](https://plnkr.co/edit/6XUHJjYy4slBpqEwAHxQ?p=preview)

```
<button ng-click="navigate()">Next</button>
<div class="outer" ng-repeat="service in services" ng-init="serviceSuffix=$index;serviceForm = 'form' +serviceSuffix">
  <h2>{{service.serviceName}} id= {{service.id}} {{serviceForm}}</h2>

  <ng-form name="{{serviceForm}}">
    <button ng-click="isValidForm(serviceSuffix)">Is Outer valid</button>
    <div class="inner" ng-repeat="spec in service.products" ng-init="specSuffix = serviceSuffix+'_'+$index; specForm = 'form' +specSuffix; ">
      <h2>{{spec.specName}} id={{spec.id}} {{specForm}}</h2>
      <ng-form name="{{specForm}}">
        <input required type="text" name="{{spec.specName}}" ng-model="spec.value">
        <span ng-show="this[specForm][spec.specName].$invalid">please enter</span>
        <button ng-click="isValidForm(specSuffix)">Is Inner valid</button>
      </ng-form>
    </div>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

To access nth form in your controller.

```
  $scope.isValidForm = function(suffix) {
    alert('form '+suffix+' valid='+$scope['form' +suffix].$invalid)
  };
```

Comment: ya I agree . but how to check this in controller ?

Comment: Giving one example but it would be best if you come with how and where do you want to check a particular form.

Comment: when i click on next button I need to check whether any one the main form  is valid or not

Comment: You can access any of the forms using the form suffix. Also you need to know the name of the form before checking valid or invalid. So if you know the form suffix Next button can check valid or invalid.

Comment: I don't want to have these many buttons in this html...I need only one button that is there in top (navigate) .

Comment: Those additional buttons are for demonstration only. They are not the solution. For Next button you can iterate over index of all services array an reconstruct the suffix to get a form name. However you don't have any fields in your mainForm. Nested forms are discouraged.